# CString Format adds null value for MySQL query

Tags: mfc, mysql-connector, c-strings

I have to add data to databse. Im using MySQL Connector in my vc++ application.
Im following below method to create and insert values to some columns in that table.

```
 if(mysql_query(&dbSql , "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS perfscoretbl (SessionID CHAR(100) NOT NULL,TagName CHAR(50) NOT NULL ,\
     Description CHAR(50) NOT NULL,TagLow CHAR(50) NOT NULL,TagHigh CHAR(50) NOT NULL, ExtremeLow CHAR(50) NOT NULL,ExtremeHigh CHAR(50) NOT NULL,\
     AvgDev CHAR(50)  NOT NULL,PVHighTime CHAR(50) NOT NULL,PVLowTime CHAR(50) NOT NULL,PV CHAR(50) NOT NULL,\
     TotalTime CHAR(50) NOT NULL,FinalDeviation CHAR(50) NOT NULL ,Score CHAR(50) NOT NULL) ")==0) 

         printf( "Table Created\n");
```

Depends on the button click i add different values to different columns in the same table.

```
CString Temp,sTmp;
sTmp="INSERT INTO perfscoretbl (SessionID, TagName, Description,TagLow,TagHigh,ExtremeLow,ExtremeHigh,AvgDev,Score) VALUES(";
Temp.Format("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%0.2f%s%0.2f%s%0.2f%s%0.2f%s%0.2f%s%0.2f%s%0.2f%s",sTmp,"'",sessionId,"','",pPerfData->sTagName,"','", \
pPerfData->sDesc,"','",pPerfData->fTagLow,"','",pPerfData->fTagHigh,"','",pPerfData->fExtremeLow,"','",pPerfData->fExtremeHigh,"','", \
pPerfData->fError,"','",pPerfData->fTagScore,"')" );

if(mysql_query(&dbSql,Temp)==0)
printf("Succeed");
```

But INSERT query failed. When i check Temp String,in the end of the string it has extra character as 0.00(null).

*Temp = "INSERT INTO perfscoretbl (SessionID, TagName, Description,TagLow,TagHigh,ExtremeLow,ExtremeHigh,AvgDev,Score) VALUES('Ins1_03122015_115222T','DPC101','DEPROP PR','16.00','18.00','11.26','11.26','100.00','0.00')**0.00(null)**"*

I checked everything but cannot correct it.
Is there anyother way for INSERT query in vc++ mysql connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the last `%0.2f%s` is unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

Complement to JijeshKV's anwser:

I'd put the commas and the apostrophes into the format string which results in far less parameters to the Format function and is far more readable, like this:

```
CString Temp,sTmp;
sTmp="INSERT INTO perfscoretbl (SessionID, TagName, Description, TagLow, TagHigh, ExtremeLow, ExtremeHigh, AvgDev, Score) VALUES(";
Temp.Format("'%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%0.2f', '%0.2f', '%0.2f', '%0.2f', '%0.2f', '%0.2f'",
             sTmp,
             sessionId,
             pPerfData->sTagName,
             pPerfData->sDesc,
             pPerfData->fTagLow,
             pPerfData->fTagHigh,
             pPerfData->fExtremeLow,
             pPerfData->fExtremeHigh,
             pPerfData->fError,
             pPerfData->fTagScore,"')"
           );
```